# Android get Tcp connection log

Tags: android

I have some trouble in getting Tcp connection log of all apps. Basically, I just read the log file "/proc/Pid/net/tcp" as used here:
http://code.google.com/p/iptableslog/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/networklog/NetStat.java?r=60cb640ac27f8b4fb06f11d9d81c94591a531862

But all the destination ip address are 0.0.0.0, though some apps are connecting to Internet.

Here is my source code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textmpid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Button buttonLoadTrafficStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonLoadTrafficStats.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<RunningAppProcessInfo> mRunningProcess = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                int i = 1;
                int a;
                String b;
                int c;
                for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo amProcess : mRunningProcess){
                    //Get name, Pid, Uid of all running process
                    System.out.println("Application: " +i+ " PID: " + amProcess.pid+ " (processName= " + amProcess.processName + " UID= "+amProcess.uid+")");
                    Log.i("Application", (i++) + "PID: " + amProcess.pid + "(processName=" + amProcess.processName + "UID="+amProcess.uid+")");
                    i++;
                    textmpid.setText("PID: "+ String.valueOf(amProcess.pid));
                    a = amProcess.pid;
                    b = String.valueOf(amProcess.pid);

                    ArrayList<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>();

                        try {
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/" + a + "/net/tcp"));
                            String line = b;
                            int z; 
                            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(" tcp Netstat line: " + line);
                                line = line.trim();
                                String[] fields = line.split("\\s+", 10);
                                int fieldn = 0;
                                for(String field : fields) {
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Field " + (fieldn++) + ": [" + field + "]");
                                    int m = fieldn; 
                                    String n = field;
                                }

                                if(fields[0].equals("sl")) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                  Connection connection = new Connection();

                                    String src[] = fields[1].split(":", 2);
                                    String dst[] = fields[2].split(":", 2);

                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: fields[1] " + fields[1]+"  fields[2] " + fields[2]);
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: src[0] " + src[0] +" src[1] " + src[1]);
                                    connection.src = getAddress(src[0]);
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: connection.src " + connection.src);
                                    connection.spt = String.valueOf(getInt16(src[1]));
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: connection.spt " + connection.spt);
                                    connection.dst = getAddress(dst[0]);
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: connection.dst " + connection.dst);
                                    connection.dpt = String.valueOf(getInt16(dst[1]));
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: connection.dpt " + connection.dpt);
                                    connection.uid = fields[7];
                                    System.out.println(" tcp Netstat: connection.uid " + connection.uid);

                                    connections.add(connection);

                            }

                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(" checknetlog() Exception: " + e.toString());
                        }                                               
                    }

                }

        });

    }

      public class Connection {
        String src;
        String spt;
        String dst;
        String dpt;
        String uid;
      }

      final String states[] = { "ESTBLSH",   "SYNSENT",   "SYNRECV",   "FWAIT1",   "FWAIT2",   "TMEWAIT",
        "CLOSED",    "CLSWAIT",   "LASTACK",   "LISTEN",   "CLOSING",  "UNKNOWN"
      };

      private final String getAddress(final String hexa) {
        try {
          final long v = Long.parseLong(hexa, 16);
          final long adr = (v >>> 24) | (v << 24) |
            ((v << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | ((v >> 8) & 0x0000FF00);
          return ((adr >> 24) & 0xff) + "." + ((adr >> 16) & 0xff) + "." + ((adr >> 8) & 0xff) + "." + (adr & 0xff);
        } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.w("NetworkLog", e.toString(), e);
          return "-1.-1.-1.-1";
        }
      }

      private final String getAddress6(final String hexa) {
        try {
          final String ip4[] = hexa.split("0000000000000000FFFF0000");

          if(ip4.length == 2) {
            final long v = Long.parseLong(ip4[1], 16);
            final long adr = (v >>> 24) | (v << 24) |
              ((v << 8) & 0x00FF0000) | ((v >> 8) & 0x0000FF00);
            return ((adr >> 24) & 0xff) + "." + ((adr >> 16) & 0xff) + "." + ((adr >> 8) & 0xff) + "." + (adr & 0xff);
          } else {
            return "-2.-2.-2.-2";
          }
        } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.w("NetworkLog", e.toString(), e);
          return "-1.-1.-1.-1";
        }
      }

      private final int getInt16(final String hexa) {
        try {
          return Integer.parseInt(hexa, 16);
        } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.w("NetworkLog", e.toString(), e);
          return -1;
        }
      }
}
```

And I also added the permission "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET".

Could someone kindly point out where I did wrong?

Comment: what do you want the connection list for?
if you are rooted, 'busybox netstat -a | grep tcp' will get you connections.  try 'wireshark' app

Comment: Um. I just want to check which site an app is connecting to, especially when it's downloading something that user does not know. Is there a way to do this without rooting the phone?

Comment: dont know.. if its download activity u interest in - most download will be on HTTP protocol. you can look into logging HTTP GET on the client ??

Answer (score 0):

Oh, when I check this log "/proc/Pid/net/tcp6", I found the correct destination ip address. It seems that the connection type is tcp6 instead of tcp.

Comment: You should probably accept your own answer. That would put this question as solved/answered